# Azure AD B2C reset a user's password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have reset the user's password using Azure AD Graph API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

When I tried to login with user's old password, AD B2C still allows the user to login. I have to restrict the access to the user's old password.  Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a replication delay that should be on the order of seconds to a minute or two.  The way that Azure AD works is that there is a Primary that handles writes (change password) and several secondary instances that handle reads (login) and it is expected to see a short delay in replicating the new password to all of the secondary instances.  See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/09/02/azure-ad-under-the-hood-of-our-geo-redundant-highly-available-distributed-cloud-directory/

Is this problem temporary or is it persistent?  Meaning after a minute can the user no longer login with the old password?  Also, is the user able to login with the new password?

Comment: I guess you are right. After few minutes the user wouldn't be able to login with the old password. It might be a delay in replication the new password. Thank you :)